# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float' in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror

I have an code for implementing in deep learning in `Tensorflow`. I use the `Keras` module

```
self.n_clusters = 10
self.alpha = 0.01
clustering_layer = ClusteringLayer(self.n_clusters, alpha=self.alpha, name='clustering')(hidden)
```

my error is mainly from above, so I on attach it.

It give me the following error:

```
--> 118         clustering_layer = ClusteringLayer(self.n_clusters, alpha=self.alpha, name='clustering')(hidden)
    119         self.model = Model(inputs=self.autoencoder.input, outputs=clustering_layer)
    120 

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.pyc in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    694         if all(hasattr(x, 'get_shape') for x in input_list):
    695           input_shapes = nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.get_shape(), inputs)
--> 696         self.build(input_shapes)
    697 
    698       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.

<ipython-input-13-8890754cc8a3> in build(self, input_shape)
     73         input_dim = input_shape[1]
     74         self.input_spec = InputSpec(dtype=K.floatx(), shape=(None, input_dim))
---> 75         self.clusters = self.add_weight(shape=(self.n_clusters, input_dim), initializer='glorot_uniform', name='clusters')
     76         if self.initial_weights is not None:
     77             self.set_weights(self.initial_weights)

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.pyc in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, constraint, partitioner, use_resource, getter)
    532         trainable=trainable and self.trainable,
    533         partitioner=partitioner,
--> 534         use_resource=use_resource)
    535 
    536     if regularizer is not None:

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.pyc in _add_variable_with_custom_getter(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, getter, overwrite, **kwargs_for_getter)
    495     new_variable = getter(
    496         name=name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=initializer,
--> 497         **kwargs_for_getter)
    498 
    499     # If we set an initializer and the variable processed it, tracking will not

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.pyc in make_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, partition_info, trainable, caching_device, validate_shape, constraint, use_resource, partitioner)
   1871       validate_shape=validate_shape,
   1872       constraint=constraint,
-> 1873       use_resource=use_resource)
   1874   return v

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in variable(initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, constraint, use_resource)
   2232                          name=name, dtype=dtype,
   2233                          constraint=constraint,
-> 2234                          use_resource=use_resource)
   2235 
   2236 

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in <lambda>(**kwargs)
   2222              constraint=None,
   2223              use_resource=None):
-> 2224   previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
   2225   for getter in ops.get_default_graph()._variable_creator_stack:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2226     previous_getter = _make_getter(getter, previous_getter)

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.pyc in default_variable_creator(next_creator, **kwargs)
   2194         collections=collections, validate_shape=validate_shape,
   2195         caching_device=caching_device, name=name, dtype=dtype,
-> 2196         constraint=constraint)
   2197   elif not use_resource and context.executing_eagerly():
   2198     raise RuntimeError(

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.pyc in __init__(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, variable_def, import_scope, constraint)
    310           name=name,
    311           dtype=dtype,
--> 312           constraint=constraint)
    313 
    314   # pylint: disable=unused-argument

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.pyc in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, constraint)
    415               with ops.name_scope("Initializer"), ops.device(None):
    416                 initial_value = ops.convert_to_tensor(
--> 417                     initial_value(), name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
    418               self._handle = _eager_safe_variable_handle(
    419                   shape=initial_value.get_shape(),

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.pyc in <lambda>()
   1858         initializer = initializer(dtype=dtype)
   1859       init_val = lambda: initializer(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
-> 1860           shape, dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
   1861       variable_dtype = dtype.base_dtype
   1862   if use_resource is None:

/usr/local/python/2.7-conda5.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.pyc in __call__(self, shape, dtype, partition_info)
    466       scale /= max(1., fan_out)
    467     else:
--> 468       scale /= max(1., (fan_in + fan_out) / 2.)
    469     if self.distribution == "normal":
    470       stddev = math.sqrt(scale)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float'
```

line 118 is my code location. The error seems to occur in tensorflow package. it give me the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float'`. I try both `python 2.7` and `python 3.6` but with same problem.

How to deal with this situation?

An very similar situation is in [github](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet/issues/83), its error can be addressed in its code, but my error seems to be happen in  `init_ops.pyc`

Comment: I use "theano" as backend, and the problem solved. Any though about that

Comment: Please add more code, in order to clarify the context. Especially since the traceback jumps back to your notebook, so you seem to work with a custom class here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that ClusteringLayer is passing a tf.Dimension object as the number of clusters, which is used to initialize the weights. Do int(self.n_clusters) instead to bypass the dimension object issues.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a very similar issue -- I have a customized `Layer`, which

- works perfectly fine when it is in `keras` (keras.version=2.24) with the tf backend (tf.version=1.14)
- raises up the same error message as described in the question when I switched to `tf.keras` (tf.version=1.14)

What suggested by @Alexandre Passos works, but it took me a while to figure out what exactly did he mean. I, therefore, share my experience below to help future friends.

Below is an example customized layer,

```py
class CustomizedLayer(Layer) :
  def __init__(self, num_feats, **kwargs) :
    self.num_feats = num_feats
    super(CustomizedLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  def build(self, input_shape) :
    weight_shape = (input_shape[-1], self.num_feats) # <----- problem
    self.weight = self.add_weight(shape=weight_shape, 
                                 ...)
    super(CustomizedLayer, self).build(input_shape)
  def call(self, inputs) :
    ...
```

the issue happens in `tf.keras`, because the `input_shape` passed is of the `tf.Dimension` type but not the `int` type, which is required by `add_weight` and also is the type passed when using `keras`.

For this reason, the same layer definition works in `keras` but not `tf.keras`.

Consequently, all you need to do is to cast the `tf.Dimension` object to `int`, namely, rewriting the line of `weight_shape` as

```py
weight_shape = (int(input_shape[-1]), self.num_feats)
```

Comment: When I casted tf.Dimension to int, it worked for me. Thank you a lot !