# How to solve the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I have a class called `MaskedDense`. Below is its structure.

```
class MaskedDense(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, activation=None, use_bias=True, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.activation = keras.activations.get(activation)
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.glorot_uniform()
        self.bias_initializer = keras.initializers.Zeros()
        self.mask_initializer = keras.initializers.Ones()
        super(MaskedDense, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(MaskedDense, self).get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            "units": self.units,
            "activation": self.activation,
            "use_bias": self.use_bias,
            "kernel_initializer": self.kernel_initializer,
            "bias_initializer": self.bias_initializer,
            "mask_initializer": self.mask_initializer
        })
        return config

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units),
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      name='kernel')

        # The mask is not trainable
        self.mask = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units),
                                      initializer=self.mask_initializer,
                                      trainable=False,
                                      name='mask')

        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),
                                        initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                        name='bias')
        else:
            self.bias = None
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: input_dim})
        self.built = True
        super(MaskedDense, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, inputs):
        output = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel * self.mask)
        if self.use_bias:
            output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias, data_format='channels_last')
        if self.activation is not None:
            output = self.activation(output)
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) >= 2
        assert input_shape[-1]
        output_shape = list(input_shape)
        output_shape[-1] = self.units
        return tuple(output_shape)

    def set_mask(self, value, feature_idx, class_idx = None):
        """
        Set the mask of [feature_idx, class_idx] to a value.
        feature_idx: index of the feature
        class_idx: index of the class (or a list of indices). None means setting the value to all the classes
        value: the value to set
        """
        weights = K.get_value(self.mask)
        assert feature_idx >= 0 and feature_idx < weights.shape[0], f"Feature index out of bound [0, ..., {weights.shape[0]-1}] -- {feature_idx} given"
        if class_idx is not None:
            if isinstance(class_idx, list):
                for idx in class_idx:
                    assert idx >= 0 and idx < weights.shape[1], f"Class index out of bound [0, ..., {weights.shape[1]-1}] -- {idx} given"
                    weights[feature_idx,idx] = value
            elif isinstance(class_idx, int):
                idx = class_idx
                assert idx >= 0 and idx < weights.shape[1], f"Class index out of bound [0, ..., {weights.shape[1]-1}] -- {idx} given"
                weights[feature_idx,idx] = value
        else:
            weights[feature_idx,:] = value
        K.set_value(self.mask, weights)

    def disable_mask(self, feature_idx, class_idx = None):
        self.set_mask(value = 0, feature_idx = feature_idx, class_idx = class_idx)

    def enable_mask(self, feature_idx, class_idx = None):
        self.set_mask(value = 1, feature_idx = feature_idx, class_idx = class_idx)

    def get_masked_weights(self):
        return K.get_value(self.mask) * K.get_value(self.kernel)
```

Then I am trying to create the model. Below is the code.

```
text_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int32")
embedded_text = Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=150, trainable=True)(text_input)

filters = [(10, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4)]
filter_layers = [Conv1D(f[0], f[1], activation='relu', trainable=True)(embedded_text) for f in filters]
max_pool_layers = [GlobalMaxPool1D()(result) for result in filter_layers]

concatenated = concatenate(max_pool_layers,axis=-1)

ans = MaskedDense(len(class_names), activation='softmax')(concatenated)

model = Model(text_input, ans)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "find_1.py", line 227, in
 <module>
    ans = MaskedDense(len(class_names), activation='softmax')(concatenated)   File
 "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
 line 746, in __call__
     self.build(input_shapes)   File "find_1.py", line 151, in build
     name='kernel')   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
 line 609, in add_weight
     aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py",
 line 639, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
     **kwargs_for_getter)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
 line 1977, in make_variable
     aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
 line 183, in __call__
     return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
 line 146, in _variable_v1_call
     aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
 line 125, in <lambda>
     previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
 line 2437, in default_variable_creator
     import_scope=import_scope)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
 line 187, in __call__
     return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)   File
 "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py",
 line 297, in __init__
     constraint=constraint)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py",
 line 409, in _init_from_args
     initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
 line 1959, in <lambda>
     shape, dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)   File "/home/user_name/miniforge3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py",
 line 473, in __call__
     scale /= max(1., (fan_in + fan_out) / 2.) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'float' in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907593/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-dimension-and-float-in-tensorf)

Comment: I am not understanding it. If you could kindly explain it a little bit it would have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `input_dim = input_shape[-1]` to `input_dim = int(input_shape[-1])` solved the problem.